# What is the best practice for storing state variables?

Tags: sql

I have to code an application to manage some items that can be purchased.
Those items can have multiple state variables :

- paid / or not
- validated by an admin / or not
- sent to client / or not
- waiting for more info / or not
- (and many more...)

**What is the best practice for storing these state variables ?**

Since different items have different needs and different possible states, I think it would be impractical to store the state variables in the "items" table, so I tried storing them in a specific table such as :

| item_id | state_var_name | state_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PAID | true |
| 1 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 1 | SHIPPED | false |
| 2 | PAID | true |
| 2 | MORE_INFOS_NEEDED | true |
| 2 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 2 | SHIPPED | false |
| 2 | CANCELLED | true |
| 3 | PAID | true |
| 3 | READY_TO_SHIP | false |
| 3 | SHIPPED | true |

(Note that all "state var names" do not necessarily exist for all items.)

But this solution seems to be slow (several seconds) when I try a query I need and I don't know if the problem is bad optimization or the number of rows viewed.

Therefore, my question is :
**Can a more experienced developer than me confirm that my design choice is valid and workable ?**
If not, what is the **best practice** for storing the item's states ?

(There is no point for me to try to optimize this if the design itself is the problem. But if it's valid, then there is hope...)

Comment: Can we see your table schema (as a `create table` statement), indexes, a rough idea of how many rows are in the table, and the slow query?

Comment: @Schwern I didn't give these informations for clarity reason. The query I have issues with uses more tables than these two, divides items by type, and count for each type the number of items that are in a certain state. the state is checked with EXIST and NOT EXIST subqueries... If I had to explain everything, the post would have been too long and much less understandable. That's why I choose to focus my question on the design choice, neglecting the optimization part.

Comment: @Schwern Items table count 800 000 rows and states table 13 000 000 rows. My query's WHERE clause identify roughly 250 000 rows to look.

Comment: Would it be fair to say you're not storing the item's state, but the item's properties? I think that's the misunderstanding with @Hade.

Comment: @Schwern Well... I guess that "properties" is indeed a better word than "state variables". (Sorry for the lack of vocabulary.) The idea is that the state is defined by all these properties combined together.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a fixed set of properties for everything, use columns. If there's a subset of properties that everything shares, put those in columns. Value columns are much easier to work with than other solutions.

For the divergent properties you can use a key/value table, like you have, or you can use JSON. They have their benefits and disadvantages.

---

If you do a key/value table, performance will rely on indexes. A structure like so will be performant searching for the properties of an item, and also all values of a key.

```
create table item_properties (
  item_id integer not null,
    foreign key item_id references(items),
  key varchar(255) not null,
  value boolean not null,

  primary key(item_id, key)
);

create index item_properties_key on item_properties(key);
```

Both these queries will use indexes and take milliseconds.

```
select * from item_properties where item_id = ?

select * from item_properties where key = ?
```

---

However, the value must always be the same type. If you have values of different types, you can store a single JSON properties field. Many of your properties might be better as timestamps; it's often useful to know *when* something happened. For example, when was it shipped? When was it paid for? When was it validated?

How JSON works varies from database to database, but you would have a single JSON column with your properties in it. It also has to be indexed to be performant, how that works also depends on the database.

---

Finally, let's keep going on asking questions about this data. Who verified it? It was paid for, but by what method? How was it shipped? What info are you waiting for?

These suggest these simple boolean values might be their own entities (ie. its own table). I couldn't say more without knowing more about your problem, but shipping info is often its own entity.

Comment: I didn't know about JSON in database, I should try that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: About your last observation : the reason why I don't want to search shipment or payment infos in their own tables is because I have many request that need to count the number of items in a certain state. (e.g. : paid, not shipped, not yet validated by an admin, with all user info collected, from a customer that is not a private individual, etc.). And i fear that such queries will be harder to read and slower to run if they need 6 or 7 joins instead of looking in a single table.

Comment: @Charles.C Joins are a fundamental part of SQL, they're the *relationships* in your *relational* database. Trying to cram multiple entities into fewer tables results in complicated, slow queries; simplicity and performance come from good table design and indexes. I understand you've been trying to spare us complexity, but we can only answer what you tell us, and it seems you've left off vital details. Finally, JSON in SQL brings its own complications; if you can solve a problem with traditional tables and joins I recommend that.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I will investigate that first.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know about '**experienced developer**' but lemme chip in. Ideally, from what I've seen around and implemented myself, I wouldn't go that way. You're having multiple records for same item in a table. Your table size will grow so large, which could impact performance for any lookup involving item as evident already.

I'll recommend you create another table *item_state* which will contain all of any possible item's state. Since state of an Item can only be one, *add an item_state column* in *item table* **referencing** *item_state table*, then persist that Item with its corresponding state's id. This way, item_state table contain only 5 records to look up whenever you make an item search. In fact, if it's a lazy loaded, it only picks the id and not the item_state record so it doesn't even search the item_state table at all.

```
create table item_state(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    state VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

create table item(
    id INT...
    //other fields
    item_state INT NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT item_item_state_fk FOREIGN KEY(item_state)
        REFERENCES item(id)
        //other relationship details...
)
```

Comment: 1) Indexing `item_id` and also `key` makes the table size irrelevant. 2) Their design does not violate normalization because this is a join table. It's ok to have multiple rows for the same foreign key in a join table. There is no data duplication. 3) If you put every possible state as columns into one table, that table will potentially have a lot of nulls. This potentially wastes a lot of space (not in this case, booleans are very small). More importantly, it means you can't tell if a property is null because it doesn't apply to the item, or because its unknown, or because of a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure how your proposed solution differs from their solution. Could you write it out in SQL?

Comment: @Schwern 2) I do not understand why it's ok to have multiple rows for same foreign key when in their case the value is boolean and once one is true, the other two rows are useless. 3) I think you didn't understand my point. If it Item table references item_state table and it's non nullable,  how can there be? Also, since item must have a state. So, you mean for every item there must be three corresponding rows in another table?

Comment: @Hade Once a boolean is true the others don't become useless. The state of an item is defined by all the variables together.

Comment: @Hade I'm still unclear about what you're proposing. Your design appears to be many-to-one, many items can refer to one item state (and the state is varchar?). Could you add some sample inserts and selects to demonstrate its use? I'd like to see how to add properties to an item, how to get an item's properties, and how to get the value of a property for a given value.

Comment: @Hade I think I see a misunderstanding. Even though the question talks about the item's state, they're really wanting to store an item's properties. For example, item 2 in the question has been paid, needs more info, is not ready to ship, has not been shipped, and has been cancelled. Each property is independent of each other (whether this is a good idea is unclear).

Comment: @Schwern Ohh. I now see what you mean. You're right, it doesn't become useless. I missed that items can have multiple states at once, on reading his question again now

Comment: @Hade Glad we figured it out. I think your instincts are correct, this is probably better done as a state machine. At least part of it.